# Array.push() throwing ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('

Tags: solidity

I would appreciate some help/explanation on the following error since I can't understand what's wrong.
simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage2); is throwing ParserError: Expected identifier but got '('

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
    SimpleStorage public simpleStorage2 = new SimpleStorage();
    
    simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage2);

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must to put this statement inside a function:

```
simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage2);
```

All operation in Solidity that change the state about your contract or read some variables you must to write into a function. In this case, because you're modifying a value about state variable, you must to put the statement above into `function` like this way:

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "./SimpleStorage.sol";

contract StorageFactory {

    SimpleStorage[] public simpleStorageArray;
    SimpleStorage public simpleStorage2 = new SimpleStorage();

    function createSimpleStorageContract() public {
        SimpleStorage simpleStorage = new SimpleStorage();
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage);
        simpleStorageArray.push(simpleStorage2);
    }
}
```